# Non-exhaustive on Haskell recursion

Tags: haskell, non-exhaustive-patterns

```
sumAllDigits :: [ Int ] -> Int  
sumAllDigits (x:xs)  
   |(x:xs) == []  = 0  
   |x >= 10  = sumDigits x + sumAllDigits xs  
   |x< 10    = x + sumAllDigits xs
```

REPORT:
 *Recursion> sumAllDigits [22,33]
 *** Exception: Recursion.hs:(76,1)-(79,34): Non-exhaustive patterns in function sumAllDigits

Comment: How can `x:xs` ever be equal to `[]`? (Hint: in the same way 1 can equal 0.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following changes will correct this for you. I prefer to make the empty list case it's own implementation to match against. Just feels more explicit to me. And then, since `x` will drop through the `>=` if it is less than, otherwise will cover those cases.

```
sumAllDigits :: [ Int ] -> Int  
sumAllDigits [] = 0
sumAllDigits (x:xs)  
   | x >= 10  = sumDigits x + sumAllDigits xs  
   | otherwise= x + sumAllDigits xs
```

Comment: That looks like it will probably fix it, but your answer would be more useful if you could explain what was wrong and how this remedies the problem.

Comment: Edited to do so. Sorry about that. On mobile and prefer to post helpful first in case of app crash or lost connection. :)

Comment: "I prefer to make the empty list case it's own implementation to match against" – this is indeed _in general_ good advice, but here you can state it rather more strongly: if `x:xs` is the only clause, the function _can never_ match an empty list!